# Compiling for iPhone 2.2.1 using Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, operating-system

I have been developing an iPhone app. and had the Base SDK set to "iPhone Device 3.0" and Deployment target set to "iPhone OS 3.0". Everything worked fine. I recently realised I actually needed to compile the project to run on devices using version 2.2.1 of the SDK, so I set the deployment target to "iPhone OS 2.2.1". Now when I hit compile I get 2079 errors all eventually pointing back to my header files saying "#endif without #if". My header files are surrounded by #ifndef/#endif clauses and I have checked every single one of them and all of these match up (since it compiles targeting 3.0 I'm assuming this isn't the problem anyway). I am using XCode 3.1.3. I have no idea what is going on and would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that you aren't using libraries that are *only* available in the 3.0 SDK. If you are using the MPMediaPlayer Framework, for example, you will probably get some compile warnings since those libraries don't exist prior to the 3.0 SDK.

My general advice for compile errors is to start with the first error and work your way one at a time. Generally, a single failure at the top will cascade and cause many more compile errors than actually exist in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I had the target SDK set to the wrong version (2.2.1), when it should have been set to 3.0.